# Правильно ли задается и очищается динамический массив в класс?

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

```
class Tree {
private:
    int n;
    int f;
    int* size = new int[n];
    int* tree = new int[f];
public:
    Tree(int valueN) {
        n = valueN;
        f = valueN * 2;
        size = new int[n];
        tree = new int[f];
    }
    ~Tree() {
        delete [] size;
        delete [] tree;
    }
```

Comment: Не надо инициализировать    `int* size = new int[n]; int* tree = new int[f];` в объявлении класса - значения `n` и `f` тут не определены. Оставьте это конструктору...

Comment: Я удалил из приватного поля инициализацию int* size и int* tree при этом заменив в конструкторе size и tree. Но теперь мои массивы не являются глобальными переменными и я не могу их использовать в своём классе. (Похоже я неправильно понял вас. Если вам не сложно, приведите пожалуйста пример кода)

Comment: Почему бы не использовать `std::vector`? Или это очередное учебное задание? В таком случае надо ещё не забыть о "правиле пяти".

Comment: См. код в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что я имел в виду:

```
class Tree {
private:
    int n, f;
    int *size, *tree;
public:
    Tree(int valueN):n(valueN),f(valueN*2),
        size(new int[valueN]),tree(new int[valueN*2])
    {
    }
    ~Tree() {
        delete [] size;
        delete [] tree;
    }
}
```

Но, как вам уже ответили, нужно бы еще написать оператор присваивания и копирующий конструктор. И они должны выполнять **глубокое** копирование, т.е. копировать не указатели `size` и `tree`, а создавать массивы и копировать их содержимое.

Примерно так:

```
Tree(const Tree& t):n(t.n),f(t.f),
    size(new int[t.n]),tree(new int[t.f])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        size[i] = t.size[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < f; ++i)
    {
        tree[i] = t.tree[i];
    }
}

Tree& operator =(const Tree& t)
{
    Tree tmp(t);
    swap(tmp);
}

private:
void swap(Tree&t)
{
    std::swap(n,t.n);
    std::swap(f,t.f);
    std::swap(size,t.size);
    std::swap(tree,t.tree);
}
```